# How to install composer in cpanel while using codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, pusher

I have no idea about that how can I install composer on `cPanel` while using `CodeIgniter` framework. Now, what am I doing I am using `pusher` for real-time notification but I have got some problem and i.e.

> Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface' not found in /home/empowclb/public_html/application/third_party/pusher/Pusher.php on line 11

Due to the cause of composer. Now, I want to install composer with `CodeIgniter` framework on `cPanel`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: you need to ask your providers.. do you have any command server access ?

Comment: Have you tried [the manual](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Set+Up+%28PHP%29+Composer)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `SSH` access to the server, please follow these instructions to setup composer in `cPanel`.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Set+Up+%28PHP%29+Composer